# How to install react-native-audio-record with Expo React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to use this (https://github.com/goodatlas/react-native-audio-record) react native package in my app. Here is what I have done. In terminal:

```
// Created a new proj (blank template)
expo init test
cd test

// Installed it
npm i react-native-audio-record
npm install

// Run the proj
npm start
```

Next, in my app.js file, I added the following line to import it:

```
// Import it
import AudioRecord from 'react-native-audio-record';
```

However, when run, I get the following error:

[IMAGE OF THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX8KD.png)

**Please let me know if you have any ideas as to how to fix this! Suggestions are greatly appreciated!**

Comment: No you cannot. `react-native-audio-record` requires the linking of native code so you can only use it in an ejected Expo app or a full React-Native app.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! I see, so if I were to setup a full react native project, it would work? How is a full react native project different from an expo app? I am new to react native if you couldnt tell!

Comment: @Andrew I also tried making a new full react native app and still get the same error. Would you happen to have an email to chat over Hangouts? Would be willing to venmo/paypal you

Comment: The reason you are getting the error in the full tract-native app is that you haven’t linked the dependency. There doesn’t look like there is a podspec for `react-native-audio-record` so it will not auto link. You need to run `react-native link react-native-audio-record`. If you continue to have issues setting up the dependency you should look to the dependency maintainer for help.